# US tourist visa - Indian citizen

Tags: usa, tourist-visas

This is about the list of documents to apply for a tourist visa to the US. I have recently divorced but waiting for my divorce decree document, which might take about 3-4 weeks more. However, I am planning to apply for a US tourist visa to attend my friend's marriage end of January 2018.

What are the points to be kept in mind while filling up the "Marital status" field in the form and what supporting documents need to be produced?

-Nuvo

Comment: The answer depends on your actual marital status.  Are you are already legally divorced but awaiting documents?  Are you awaiting the legal finalization of your divorce?